# "Active directory users and computers" are duplicated in my Windows Server 2019

Tags: esxi, windows-server-2019, vcenter

When I click tools from server management I find that.

“Active directory users and computers” are duplicated in my Windows server 2019 and this happened after I used vCenter to move my physical Domain Controller to ESXI.

It is duplicated in both the physical and the ESXI VM. I do not understand what causes this issue.

Does anyone know what happened?

[image]